# AWS DynamoDB - How to design a table/index that can efficiently retrieve large numbers of items with a specific value/state

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that records job status (just a few) of each item. Say `["initial", "executing", "executed"]` and there are a large number of items in this table with different job status.

My problem is how I should design a table/index that it's able to quickly retrieve all jobs with a specified job status.

I've thought about creating an index with job status as a hash key. This seems to work but I found it's treated as bad design in dynamodb.

Is there a better design to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, no, there is no better solutions to that kind of problem.

As they say in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html):

> The partition key portion of a table's primary key determines the logical partitions in which a table's data is stored. This in turn affects the underlying physical partitions. Provisioned I/O capacity for the table is divided evenly among these physical partitions. Therefore a partition key design that doesn't distribute I/O requests evenly can create "hot" partitions that result in throttling and use your provisioned I/O capacity inefficiently.
>
> ...
>
> If a single table has only a small number of partition key values, consider distributing your write operations across more distinct partition key values. In other words, structure the primary key elements to avoid one "hot" (heavily requested) partition key value that slows overall performance.

It means that if the values has only few different values – no matter is it a table's partition key, or is it an index's partition key – the values will be put inside the same partition and that will make it "hot" and you won't be able to distribute the load on them. It's like a "microscan": you're not scanning the whole table (good news), only a single partition. But that partition still has a lot of data and you're doing a full scan of that partition (bad news).

You can improve it a little bit with [parallel scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan) (you can scan over the whole table or GSI), still it's not a silver bullet.

Event in general: if you are distributing a lot of data by a few unique values it's a bottleneck.

Can you look at this problem from a different point of view? Looks like you are doing some logic for job's state transitions. Could you switch to [DynamoDB streams / Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)? With DynamoDB streams enabled whenever your record changes, DynamoDB will send that change in a stream, so it can be consumed by interested parties. You can make a Lambda function that will read that stream and react on every change as soon as it happens (well, not instantly, but the lag is minimal). If you can refactor your workflow to this event-driven model you won't need any queries or scans.